# On marginal subgroups and automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, universal-algebra, automorphism-group, characteristic-subgroups

In the theory of [marginal](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Marginal_subgroup) subgroups there is a following statement:

> Suppose $G$ is a group, $M$ is a proper marginal subgroup of $G$. Suppose $\alpha \in {\rm Aut}(G)$ such that $\forall g \in G$ $\alpha(b)b^{-1} \in M$. Then, $|{\rm Stab}_\alpha| > 1$.

Here ${\rm Stab}_\alpha = \{g \in G| \alpha(g) = g\}$.

Proof:

Suppose it were, for a word $w$. Any two elements $x, \alpha(x) \in G$ belong to the same coset, so there are elements $a,b \in M$ such that $x'=ax=xb$. So $w(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is fixed by $\alpha$ (of $x_1,\dots,x_n$, and hence of $w(x_1,\dots,w_n)$). Hence $w$ can only take values in the stabiliser of $\alpha$ which thus in case when $M$ is proper should be non-trivial, Q.E.D.

My question is:

Can this statement be generalised to something like:

> Suppose $G$ is a group, $M$ is a marginal subgroup of $G$. Suppose $\alpha \in {\rm Aut}(G)$ such that $\forall g \in G$ $\alpha(b)b^{-1} \in M$. Then, $|{\rm Stab}_\alpha| > f([G:M])$.

If it can, what $f$ can be taken there?

Comment: In the first box "$\alpha(b)b^{-1}=M$" mean to be $\in$ rather than $=$? Same in the second box...